# filtrar array a partir de otro array

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de filtrar un array, con los valores de otro array, con la condición que sea mayor a 0, en este caso los campos FAENAS Y MULTAS, y deseo que la respuesta final sea en un solo array, cumpliendo mi condición, He tratado de la siguiente manera pero no consigo el resultado que quisiera.

```js
const concepts = [
  {c_prod:"000004",l_prod:"FAENAS"},
  {c_prod:"000001",l_prod:"MULTAS"}
];

const datos = [
  {n_docu:"23248169",l_agen:"USUARIO",FAENAS:"0.00",MULTAS:"0.00"},
  {n_docu:"71377558",l_agen:"SIMEON",FAENAS:"5.00",MULTAS:"0.00"}, 
  {n_docu:"45877558",l_agen:"PAUL",FAENAS:"10.00",MULTAS:"2.00"}, 
  {n_docu:"71123558",l_agen:"ERIK",FAENAS:"15.00",MULTAS:"0.00"}, 
  {n_docu:"46117631",l_agen:"EGUAVIL",FAENAS:"0.00",MULTAS:"1.00"}
];

const result = concepts.map(concept => {
  const { l_prod } = concept;
  return datos.filter(d => d[l_prod] > 0);
});

console.log(result);
```

El resultado que desearía obtener:

```js
[
  {n_docu:"45877558",l_agen:"PAUL",FAENAS:"10.00",MULTAS:"2.00"}
]
```

Ya que es el único que cumpliría la condición que deseo.

Answer (score 1):

El filtro debe aplicarse sobre el arreglo que contiene los datos a analizar y, dentro, recorrer conceptos para verificar si ambos son mayor que cero. Tú lo estás haciendo al revés, comenzando por conceptos.

```js
const concepts = [
  {c_prod:"000004",l_prod:"FAENAS"},
  {c_prod:"000001",l_prod:"MULTAS"}
];

const datos = [
  {n_docu:"23248169",l_agen:"USUARIO",FAENAS:"0.00",MULTAS:"0.00"},
  {n_docu:"71377558",l_agen:"SIMEON",FAENAS:"5.00",MULTAS:"0.00"}, 
  {n_docu:"45877558",l_agen:"PAUL",FAENAS:"10.00",MULTAS:"2.00"}, 
  {n_docu:"71123558",l_agen:"ERIK",FAENAS:"15.00",MULTAS:"0.00"}, 
  {n_docu:"46117631",l_agen:"EGUAVIL",FAENAS:"0.00",MULTAS:"1.00"}
];

// El filtro se debe aplicar en datos
let result = datos.filter(dato =>
    // Filtrar conceptos con los valores de cada dato
    // Devuelve verdadero solo si ambos conceptos son mayor que cero
    concepts.filter(concept => dato[concept.l_prod] > 0).length == 2
);
console.log(result);
```